# Make Class member attribute of type Array(T) accept 2D arrays of T

Tags: crystal-lang

I've defined a `Container` class. In the @values attribute, I need to store an array, or a 2D array, and elements in those arrays can be Int32 or Float64. If I initialize it like this:

```
class Container

  def initialize(value) 
    @values = values
  end

end
```

I get an error: `@values : Type, is inferred from assignments to it across the whole program.`

If I define it like this:

```
class Container

  def initialize(value : Array) 
    @values = values
  end

end
```

I get: `can't use Array(T) as the type of instance variable @values of Container(T), use a more specific type`

How can I make this class more flexible so I can do:

```
Container.new([1,2,3])
Container.new([1.0, 3.0, 4.0])
Container.new([[1, 2], [4,3,2],[1]])
Container.new([[1.0, 4.5], [2.2, 0.0]])
```

Comment: What is the use case for the Container? What can you do with it?

Comment: The goal is to be able to use it as a numpy ndarray, to be able to apply some matrices operations on it if it's square, operations between ndarrays if their shape allows it, and define it with the type of each element and the shape of the array. The issue is with the type of element. As I wrote above, I couldn't find how to make it work for both 1D and 2D arrays, and for both 32Int and 64Float

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing some digging, there does seem to be an [official way of doing this](https://crystal-lang.org/2015/08/24/its-a-typeof-magic.html).  However, it must be planned because using that syntax in the constructor gives me the following as of Crystal 0.20.1

```
def initialize(value : Array(Array | Int32 | Float64))
    @values = value
end

Error in line 3: can't use Array(T) in unions yet, use a more specific type
```

If I am understanding correctly from your sample data, it seems like types will be homogeneous (i.e. arrays will always contain one specific type).  If this is the case, you can simply overload the constructor.  It's not a pretty solution, but perhaps it can tie you over.

```
class Container

  def initialize(value : Array(Array)) 
    @values = value
    calculate
  end

  def initialize(value : Array(Int32))
    @values = value
    calculate
  end

  def initialize(value : Array(Array(Int32)))
    @values = value
    calculate
  end

  def initialize(value : Array(Array(Float64)))
    @values = value
    calculate
  end

  def initialize(value : Array(Float64))
    @values = value
    calculate
  end

  def calculate
    # do stuff here
  end

end

Container.new([1,2,3])
Container.new([1.0, 3.0, 4.0])
Container.new([[1, 2], [4,3,2],[1]])
Container.new([[1.0, 4.5], [2.2, 0.0]])
```

**Edit:**

It seems you can use @faaq's solution without specifying the type thanks to the comment by @Sija.  They also shared [this sample code](https://play.crystal-lang.org/#/r/1hqt), which I think is much cleaner than overloading the constructor.

Comment: You understood correctly! Didn't think of overloading the constructor. Good idea thanks a lot! So you're saying that the first way should work in a future version ? It's a more concise/elegant way.

Comment: I *believe* it will, but I'm not entirely sure.  Crystal's gitter is a good place to get stuff answered, and I'll ask the community when I get a chance too.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't use Generics?

```
class Container(Type)

  def initialize(@values : Type) 
    pp @values
    pp typeof(@values)
  end

end

value = [1,2,3]
Container(typeof(value)).new(value)
value = [1.0, 3.0, 4.0]
Container(typeof(value)).new(value)
value = [[1, 2], [4,3,2],[1]]
Container(typeof(value)).new(value)
value = [[1.0, 4.5], [2.2, 0.0]]
Container(typeof(value)).new(value)
```

The output is:

```
@values # => [1, 2, 3]
typeof(@values) # => Array(Int32)
@values # => [1.0, 3.0, 4.0]
typeof(@values) # => Array(Float64)
@values # => [[1, 2], [4, 3, 2], [1]]
typeof(@values) # => Array(Array(Int32))
@values # => [[1.0, 4.5], [2.2, 0.0]]
typeof(@values) # => Array(Array(Float64))
```

Comment: Indeed, this could work. However, it makes using this class a pain. Writing `Container(typeof([[1.0, 4.5], [2.2, 0.0]])).new([[1.0, 4.5], [2.2, 0.0]])` instead of `Container.new([[1.0, 4.5], [2.2, 0.0]])`. Using the solution above, I can declare instances easily and get the type at the same time. But I agree, this is shorter in the class itself, but I'm more interested in the usability right now. Thanks a lot for providing a solution though

Comment: You don't need to explicitly pass the `Type` argument, `Container.new(value)` would work too.